# Trigger button click on other element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have "copy-button" component which using in many place of the app and allows to copy information to clipboard. It has two bindings buttonText: '@', buttonClass: '@', which allows to change text of the button and add class for styling. What i need to do is change the view of copy-button and add icons instead of default button. But i can't trigger click event on this icon.

```
<div class="copy_code_bttn_block">
     <copy-button button-text="b" button-class="copy_bttn"></copy-button>
     <i class="icon-copy-code"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: simply call that function, which you are using for button.

Comment: @Durga the problem is "copy-button" is other component inside component with "copy_code_bttn_block" and "copy-button" has functionality and different binding, so i just cant call on function from button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copyButton.html

```
    <button ng-click="onAdd()">Add
       <i class="icon-copy-code" ng-if="isIcon === true"></i>
    </button>
```

copyButton.component.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('copyButton', { 
        templateUrl: 'copyButton.html', 
        controller: copyButtonController, 
        bindings: { 
            onAdd: '&',
            isIcon: '=' 
        }
    });
```

here onAdd can be in copyButtonController or in parent controller

use of copyButton component

```
<copy-button on-add="ctrl.add()" is-icon="true">Test</copy-button>
```

Comment: i have this functionality inside copy-button component already. What i need to do is save the button functionality, but change the view of a button, like change the icon of the button. And as copy-button used in many place i can't change the view of a copy-button, only from other component which use this copy-button inside. If it's not clear, i can add some details.

Comment: you mean, you want to add icon with this button and want the same click functionality for icon as of button. but this icon is not required for other places, and you wont add it to the component of copyButton.

if yes, then you can pass a variable in on the basis of condition you can show icon inside button.

Comment: changed the descriptions for clearness, and yes, you are right about your hypothesis

Comment: modified the answer